# How can i disable the auto-refreshing feature of react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

So react-admin seems to have a feature where if you're idle for a little while and come back it will reload the data, presumably to make sure you're looking at the most up to date version of a record.

This is causing some issues for my editing feature that has some custom components. Is there a way to disable this auto-reload feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-refresh is triggered by the loading indicator (the spinner icon that you see in the top right part of the app bar).

You can disable the auto-refresh by replacing the loading indicator by your own.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import { useRefreshWhenVisible, RefreshIconButton } from 'react-admin';

const useStyles = makeStyles(
    {
        loader: {
            margin: 14,
        },
        loadedIcon: {},
    },
    { name: 'RaLoadingIndicator' }
);

const LoadingIndicator = props => {
    const { classes: classesOverride, className, ...rest } = props;
    useRefreshWhenVisible(); // <= comment this line to disable auto-refresh
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.admin.loading > 0);
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    return loading ? (
        <CircularProgress
            className={classNames('app-loader', classes.loader, className)}
            color="inherit"
            size={18}
            thickness={5}
            {...rest}
        />
    ) : (
        <RefreshIconButton className={classes.loadedIcon} />
    );
};

LoadingIndicator.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    width: PropTypes.string,
};

export default LoadingIndicator;
```

You'll also need to put this button in a custom AppBar, inject your AppBar in a custom Layout, and use that Layout in your Admin, as explained in [the react-admin Theming documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#layout-from-scratch).

Comment: I see. Looking through many of the issues on the repo it looks like there is some desire to make the automatic refresh configurable so that'd be great to see when it is prioritized.

In the meantime I am just going to use a SimpleForm instead of a rff <Form> element... it looks like a <SimpleForm> inside of an <Edit> seems to work in telling the library to avoid auto-refreshing.

Thank you for all the hard work on the project Francois, it has been a pleasure to use; especially with the new TS support!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to turn off auto-refresh by dispatching the `setAutomaticRefresh` action from `react-admin`:

```js
import { setAutomaticRefresh } from 'react-admin';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

// inside component
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(setAutomaticRefresh(false))
```

This action was added [here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/5152/files) as part of release [3.8.2](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/releases/tag/v3.8.2).

Answer (score 0):

As of react-admin 4.x it [uses react-query](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#queryclient) for dealing with that part of data handling. You can set a custom `queryClient` on the `<Admin>` Component to disabled the `refetchOnWindowFocus` feature of react-query.

```
//App.tsx

import { Admin } from "react-admin";
import { QueryClient } from "react-query";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false
        }
    },
});

export const App = () => (
    <Admin 
       queryClient={queryClient}
       //...otherProperties
    />
);
```